# Is there an open source application to create applications without programming?

Tags: android, open-source, web-apps, iphone-app

I am looking for some type of program or free code application with which I can create an application for my business from GUI without the need to program. I have seen some, but have the obligation to be on the server of the platform in question. I show you an example: https://www.mobincube.com/es/ Thank you.

I EDIT THE QUESTION:
What I am trying to do is a native application for Android and iOs for a store in which to add all the details I mentioned before. I'm looking for a course where I can create this application with React, since the software that automatically makes the application from GUI, does not think it's possible.
I already did something with React, so I hope you can help me find a course or similar where I can study how to create the application I need.
Thank you.

Comment: I haven't tried it but BotChief might work. Please edit your question telling price range your os and other needs.

Comment: What kind of app do want? I mean what should it do?

Comment: Hello @Mawg , I want to make an APP for a store: catalog, shopping cart, card payment, user registration, etc. If I found a React.js tutorial, I would try to do it, but I can not find any course where they do something similar. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit too lone to be a comment, so I have to post it as an answer, sorry.

First, be aware that [React.Js](https://reactjs.org/) is for web sites and [React Native](http://www.reactnative.com/) is for Android and iPHone. The web one came first, then the smartphone version. They are similar, but you can't swap them around.

If you want a web site (which seems likely, when you speak of servers), and say

> I want to make an APP for a store: catalog, shopping cart, card payment, user registration, etc

Then [Drupal](https://www.drupal.org/) can easily do that for you, with no need to code, just plug together the modules and configure them.

There are other solutions, but Drupal is probably the largest and most popular. We certainly have [a sister site](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/) dedicated to it.

If its a native Android & iOS app you are after, then it gets trickier, but please let us know.

Hope this helped.

Comment: Thank you @Mawg I think it does not express my needs well. What I really need to do is a native application for Android and iOs. Edit the question to see if someone can help me. Thank you

Comment: If you don't find an answer then your only chance is to fall back to browser-based, and Drupal would make it very simple. I am very sorry that I cannot help you, but will mark this question as a favourite, because I want to see the answer too. Good luck